# Is there a way to self host an access point for cellular networks?

Tags: cellular-network, apn, access-point

Let me preface this by explaining why I’m asking. I have a very inexpensive prepaid cellular plan, but the drawback to it being cheap is that the access point is located in Hong Kong, meaning all the data on that line must go through at least one server in Hong Kong. The plan allows you to change the APN settings, meaning in theory (I may be wrong here, I don’t know much about this), any access point reachable from the network could be used to route data. If this assumption is correct, I am interested in running my own access point, to make my connection faster, by avoiding the need to route through servers across the world. I tried searching this on google, but to no avail. Does anyone know if this is possible? Or what software I could use, if it exists?

(Also, I’m sorry if this is the wrong forum, but it seemed like the best match based on other things when searching for “cellular”)

Thank you.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming, and it doesn't seem like this is a problem you would solve by writing your own software.  So it is off topic here.

Comment: If you don’t mind me asking, where should I go for an answer? As I said there didn’t seem to be any other good places for this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.  All I can tell you is that *this* is not a good place for it.  You can browse the [other Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), but make sure to check their respective help pages before posting to see what is on topic there.  SE does not cover every possible topic, so there may not be any that will fit; if so, you will have to look elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: You could try [su] or [sf], @Robert.